# Cauchy Goursat, why triangles?

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Cauchy Goursat**: Let
>   $f$ be analytic in a simply connected domain $D$.If $C$ is a simple closed contour that lies in $D$ , then $$\int_C f(z) dz = 0.$$

I've been reading a lot of proofs on this theorem and all of them treats the contour $C$ as a triangle at first, but doesn't explain why it is sufficient to only show for triangles. Is it because every other simply connected curve is homotopic to a triangle?

Also, why are we allowed to assume, without any loss of generality, that one of the interior triangles is bigger than the other $3$?

Comment: nitpicking: is it Gourst or Goursat?

Comment: @abel, it is Goursat.

Comment: from what i have seen it seems that you can break any region can be partitioned into triangles. and the sum of the integrals is the integral over the boundary.

Comment: @abel, that's only true for polygons right? What happens if we have a circle or any convex path that has curvature?

Comment: as long as the boundary is piecewise continuous it should be alright. you can always approximate the boundary by polygons.

Comment: @abel, so its "kind of" like a homotopy?

Comment: in homotopy, you don't have triangulations/partitions. you only care about the boundary and not the interior. here you need to care about both the boundary and the interior.

Comment: A rectifiable curve in some open set $U$ can be uniformly approximated by a polygonal curve. Look at the proof of the homotopy version of Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @Hawk: The proof it for triangles first since it is easy to divide a triangle in 4 triangles of half size. (it also works for rectangles). After that, you can divide a polygon into triangles ( it wouldn't work in general to divide it into rectangles...).

Comment: A precursor of this theorem is the complex Leiniz-Newton $\int_{\gamma} F'(z) dz = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))$. So the Cauchy-Goursat was fine for elementary functions with a known anti-derivative. I guess it was the desire to have the antiderivative for all nice (i.e. analytic) functions, at least as an integral

Answer (score 0):

First you prove cauchy-goursat for closed triangles and $f$ holomorph in an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Then you prove that if in adition $U$ is convex, then $f$ has a primitive in $U$.

Then you prove cauchy theorem for $U$ in convex set: you just use ths Leibniz-Newton formula in any closed path and it gives zero.

This way you get the result without having to triangulate the closed curve.